# Change XML Version from 1.0 to 1.1 with ElementTree?

Tags: xml, python-2.7, jenkins, elementtree, xml-1.1

I'm using the Element tree library to modify an xml file and then convert the element tree back to xml.
In the process of doing so the xml version changes (1.1 -> 1.0).
However, I cannot perform my necessary rest calls to the Jenkins job because of this flawed xml file.

```
config_xml = server.get_job_config("Automation Enhancement Template")
root = xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring(config_xml)
```

do some manipulation on element tree. Now convert back to xml file

```
xmlstr = ET.tostring(tree._root, encoding="UTF-8", method='xml')
```

Here is the difference between the original config file vs the edited

```
<?xml version='1.1' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
```

Comment: Why is XML 1.1 used at all? It is very seldom necessary to choose XML 1.1 instead of 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

The version is hard coded, so build a custom fork of ElementTree\SimpleXMLWriter.py
[py-elementtree/elementtree/SimpleXMLWriter.py](https://github.com/vkris/py-elementtree/blob/master/elementtree/SimpleXMLWriter.py)

```
class XMLWriter:

def __init__(self, file, encoding="us-ascii"):
    if not hasattr(file, "write"):
        file = open(file, "w")
    self.__write = file.write
    if hasattr(file, "flush"):
        self.flush = file.flush
    self.__open = 0 # true if start tag is open
    self.__tags = []
    self.__data = []
    self.__encoding = encoding

def __flush(self):
    # flush internal buffers
    if self.__open:
        self.__write(">")
        self.__open = 0
    if self.__data:
        data = string.join(self.__data, "")
        self.__write(escape_cdata(data, self.__encoding))
        self.__data = []

##
# Writes an XML declaration.

def declaration(self):
    encoding = self.__encoding
    if encoding == "us-ascii" or encoding == "utf-8":
        self.__write("<?xml version='1.0'?>\n")
    else:
        self.__write("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='%s'?>\n" % encoding)
```